# Error when I am trying to connect between Azure Data factory and Azure Data lake Gen2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

Hello Azure Data factory experts,
I have this error I am trying to connect from Azure data factory to Data lake Gen2 by creating Linked services in Azure data factory, but I got this error.
How can anyone help?

BR,
Mohammed

> ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: Storage operation '' on container
> 'XXXXXXXXXX' get failed with 'Operation returned an invalid status
> code 'Forbidden''. Possible root causes: (1). It's possible because
> the service principal or managed identity don't have enough permission
> to access the data. (2). It's possible because some IP address ranges
> of Azure Data Factory are not allowed by your Azure Storage firewall
> settings. Azure Data Factory IP ranges please refer
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses..
> Account: 'azurestoragforalltype'. ErrorCode:
> 'AuthorizationPermissionMismatch'. Message: 'This request is not
> authorized to perform this operation using this permission.'.
> RequestId: '83628e11-d01f-0020-33c3-cc8430000000'. TimeStamp: 'Fri, 29
> Oct 2021 12:49:39 GMT'.. Operation returned an invalid status code
> 'Forbidden' Activity ID: ef66fc97-6bbb-4d4e-99fb-95c0ba3a4c31.

Comment: Have you already assigned your managed identity the necessary permissions and have you whitelisted azure services on the ADLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you should assign yourself at least contributor access to the lake and then try connect to the lake using managed identity from adf, this should solve your problem [image]

Comment: Would it be possible without the contributor access? I have the same issue but I will not be getting it because of security policy.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the different authentication types which Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 connector supports:

- Account key authentication
- Service principal authentication
- System-assigned managed identity authentication
- User-assigned managed identity authentication

As per your error message you might be using service principal or managed identity authentication method in Azure data lake Gen2 connector.

You must grant proper permissions for service principal/managed identity. Grant at least Execute permission for ALL upstream folders and the file system, along with Read permission for the files to copy. Alternatively, in **Access control (IAM)**, grant at least the **Storage Blob Data Reader role**.

You can check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory#service-principal-authentication) to see examples on how the permissions works in Azure data lake Gen2.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this issue is resolved. Per MICROSOFT documentation which NiharikaMoola-MT has mentioned. You need to grant service principal at storage account IAM.

At least storage blob data reader access is required

[image: How to add access]

Verify the access.

[image: validate the access once you added]

Hope this helps, if so Accept the solution so that it helps others and issue is resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).